# Would this make sense when approaching a customer? 你需要帮助吗? 好的, 如果你需要某物, 告诉我

Tags: mandarin

Let's say the customer is shopping in a furniture store and they only speak Chinese.

If I approached & said 你需要帮助吗? 好的, 如果你需要某物, 告诉我. would it sound natural? (Assuming tones/etc are good).

Basically I'm trying to say: Hello, do you need any help? If you need any assistance, let me know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"你需要帮助吗? 好的, 如果你需要**某物**, 告诉我." sounds natural if you are responsible for the promotion of a specific line of merchants, such as electronic items, cosmetics, or apparel .... Otherwise, in general, you can simply say,

- 你需要帮助吗? (好的, 您慢看.) 如果有什麼需要, 請隨時告诉我.

Or, simply replace 某物(a specific item) with 什麼(anything in the store) in the original sentence.